# UAC Settings Group Policy using powershell failed

Tags: windows, powershell, gpo

Based on Group policy setting list here under security tab line 158 from Microsoft: [Group Policy List](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56946)

```
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin
```

And referring to this registry [ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gpsb/341747f5-6b5d-4d30-85fc-fa1cc04038d4). I try to set it using *Set-GPRegistryValue* to assigned the policy to my GPO but failed. While other registry from administrative template works as it is.

This is how it suppose to look like: [ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin using Group Policy Management Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEJg2.jpg)

I using this powershell command to create and assign this policy:

```
Set-GPRegistryValue -Name "MyLabGPO" -Key "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -ValueName "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" -Type DWord -Value 0
```

and this is how it looks like: [Failed using powershell ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin UAC GPO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFVDB.png)

Which put the registry under *Policies > Administrative Templates > Extra Registry Settings*

Can anyone point out what is the problem or is there anything I miss? Thank you

Comment: I think you want to set value "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" to DWORD 0 in that registry path

Comment: Hi, Thank you for notifying. I already corrected the proper example for this issue. Even with *ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin* in place, the issue still persist. 

Did you mean *-Value* should be *ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin* instead *0*?

Comment: I have already tried that. Successfully failed .

Comment: No, the Value should be 0 (from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gpsb/341747f5-6b5d-4d30-85fc-fa1cc04038d4?redirectedfrom=MSDN)). Perhaps you should use `-GUID` instead of the `-Name` parameter, as the display name is not guaranteed to be unique in the domain..

Comment: `PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> Set-GPRegistryValue -Guid 19fc3c9d-6676-4297-9a4f-52d188f197f6 -Key "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -ValueName "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" -Type DWord -Value 0`

result : same as before

Comment: The output says that the displayname cannot be found, so that is the `MyLabGPO`. Are you sure you're not seeing the result of earlier attempts?

Comment: Thank you for response. I'm sure. After the command executed, the output show the display name which is `MyLabGPO` and its corresponding GUID `19fc3c9d-6676-4297-9a4f-52d188f197f6`. This powershell command correctly assigned this policy to the `MyLabGPO` but its doesn't assigned it to `Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies/Security Options > User Account Control` but it still falls under `Policies > Administrative Templates > Extra Registry Settings`, Can it be because of admx file or something like that, which causing this issue?